# Go: Unused variable

Tags: go

I am trying to execute a SQL statement in the code below. However, `sqlRes` is unused and therefore cannot be compiled. I do not need the variable, but I need to declare it because `Exec()` returns multiple values.

How do I approach this?

```
stmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT person SET name=?")
sqlRes, err := stmt.Exec(person.Name)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace `sqlRes` with the [blank identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) (`_`). From [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments):

> The blank identifier provides a way to ignore right-hand side values in an assignment:
>
> ```
> _ = x       // evaluate x but ignore it
> x, _ = f()  // evaluate f() but ignore second result value
> ```

Example:

```
stmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT person SET name=?")
_, err = stmt.Exec(person.Name)
```

Comment: I tried that, but I am getting `no new variables on left side of :=`

Comment: @PatrickReck: I've corrected my answer. That was happening because `err` had already been declared in the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to avoid the `no new variables` error is to wrap the check in an
`if` block:

```
if _, err := stmt.Exec(person.Name); err != nil {
   panic(err)
}
```

https://golang.org/ref/spec#If_statements