# How to tell Go compiler to ignore unused variable?

Tags: go

I have code that loops through each rune of a string like so:

```
for i, character := range "abcdefghjklmnopqrstuv" {
    fmt.Printf("character and i: ", character, i)
}
```

However, I have no need do anything with `i`. I only need that for the loop to work. If I leave `i` out of `fmt.Printf`, the compiler complains that I have defined something I did not use. If I leave `i` in, it clutters my console output.

How can I can tell the compiler to ignore the unused variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid annoying error “declared and not used”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743841/how-to-avoid-annoying-error-declared-and-not-used) or [Go: Unused variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802798/go-unused-variable)

Comment: Thank you. It does!

Comment: Late in the game, but I've had enought of unused variable error, so I've created a GoLand plugin to solve it similar to GoImports tool:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/20933-painlessgo

Preview: https://youtu.be/sVVlDtQUXtU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the blank identifier `_`:

```
for _, character := range "abcdefghjklmnopqrstuv" {
    fmt.Printf("character: ", character)
}
```

This is [covered in the Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/17).

Comment: @Mamun you don't need to delete the question. Duplicate questions can help someone who is searching for results by creating more phrasings of the same question.

Comment: Great. Thank you. I will keep it.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the confusion.

Unlike most program languages Go does not allow unused variables. This is because of a design decision to enforce that on this level unlike as a optional choice for each developer as other languages do.

So you can use the blank identifier as another answer mentioned but this is because of the way Go works.